# Im trying to delete a mysql file using php here is the code once delete is pressed nothing happens any ideas?

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to delete a mysql file using php here is the code once delete is pressed nothing happens any ideas?

delete.php

```
<?php
  include("db.php");  

    $id =$_REQUEST['PlayerID'];


    // sending query
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM Player WHERE PlayerID = '$id'")
    or die(mysql_error());      

    header("Location: usersOnline.php");
?>
```

calling it here from separate file

```
echo"<td><font face = 'Verdana' size = '3' color='black'> <a href ='del.php?Player=$id'><center>Delete</center></a>";
```

Comment: If someone wanted to ruin your day:
The string "' or '1'='1" would delete all Players
The string "'; drop table Player;" would drop the whole table. Look into parameterized queries.

Answer (score 2):

You have `?Player=$id`, but your code is looking for `$_REQUEST['PlayerID']`.  Those two terms need to match.

---

Your code is also vulernable to SQL injection.  Look into using parameterized queries with PDO or mysqli.